# What does Sri Caitanya Carita 2.15-16 mean?

Tags: vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Sri Caitanya Carita 2.15-16 says this:

> .....Then, the Lord, who is known as the annihilator of the armies of the demons, **gave breast milk to those most exalted of godly men**. And, as they gazed upon the Supreme Lord, whose beautiful eyes were filled with tender compassion, His associates felt joy. (Sri Caitanya-carita 2.15-16)....

My question is, what do these verses mean?  How do Prabhupada and other Gaudiya Vaishnavas interpret these verses?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60163/discussion-on-question-by-alba-what-does-sri-caitanya-carita-2-15-16-mean).

Answer (score 6):

Here is the structure of Chaitanya Charitamrit(CC).

CC is divided into three parts

1. Adi Leela
2. Madhya Leela
3. Antya Leela

Adi lila deals with Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's life before Sanyas(till the age of 24 years)

Madhya Leela mainly contains His pastimes when He went on tour of India.

The last part,Antya Lila speaks about His pastimes in Jagannath Puri.

Each of these sections have chapters and each chapter in tern has verses.
Now from your question we know that you are talking about 2.15-16 i.e. Chapter 2, verse 15-16. But which Lila? That we do not know. In any case I'l link below Prabhupada's translation of verses 2.15-16 of all three Leelas.

Adi Lila [2.15-16](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/2)

> [Lord Brahmā said:] “The opulences of the impersonal Brahman spread
>   throughout the millions and millions of universes. That Brahman is but
>   the bodily effulgence of Govinda.
>
> “I worship Govinda. He is my Lord. Only by His grace am I empowered to
>   create the universe.”

Madhya Leela [2.15-16](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/2)

> Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu used to express His mind in this way: “Where
>   is the Lord of My life, who is playing His flute? What shall I do now?
>   Where should I go to find the son of Mahārāja Nanda?
>
> “To whom should I speak? Who can understand My disappointment? Without
>   the son of Nanda Mahārāja, My heart is broken.”

Antya Leela [2.15-16](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/2)

> In this way Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu delivered the entire three worlds,
>   not only by His personal presence but also by empowering others. I
>   shall briefly describe how He empowered a living being in Bengal.
>
> In Āmbuyā-muluka there was a person named Nakula Brahmacārī, who was a
>   perfectly pure devotee, greatly advanced in devotional service.

So from this we know that the source from where you read this verse is a very very bad translation to say the least. It is nowhere even little related to correct translation.

In any case you can read Chaitanya Charitamrit [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc).

Comment: The Chaitanya Charita is a different text than the Chaitanya Charitamrita.  Here's the relevant chapter of the Chaitanya Charita: http://redzambala.com/krishna-caitanya/sri-krishna-caitanya-carita-book-2-chapter-16.html

Comment: @keshavSrinivasan I've been connected to iskcon for over 3 yrs nw. Never heard of this book. The only 2 texts that i know describes life of lord Chaitanya r Chaitanya Charitamrit nd Chaitanya Bhagavad. I will try to find out about this book nd hw authentic it is.

Comment: The Chaitanya Charita is actually the oldest biography of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu; it was composed by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's shishya Murari Gupta, as opposed to the Chaitanya Charitamrita which was composed by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's shishya's shishya Krishnadasa Kaviraja.

Comment: By the way, I found a reference to this incident in the Chaitanya Bhagavatam: http://causeofallcauses.com/bhagm18.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  I read the reference causeofallcauses.com/bhagm18.htm and this is so beautiful an so clear I do not understand how this drama could be used in such a wrong way by others as I originally manifested it had disturbed me so much. I must thank you very much and I wish to use this reference to pacify other minds that may have become disturbed.

Comment: @Alba Yeah, if you want you can write an answer to your own question, using that Chaitanya Bhagavatam link to show that it was a drama.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I checked again. The Chaitanya Bhagavat Madhya lila has only 17 chapters. I checked on Iskcon desire tree. They have also come up with printed copy of this. there are only 17 chapters. 18th chapters is probably latter addition and not sure about the validity of incident.